# How do I rename a Play project?

Tags: playframework

See this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dhMeXgmA) for commands in Play! `help`, `project`, and `tasks` displays.

Is there no other way to rename a project other than creating a new project and copying files over?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always edit the `project/Build.scala` file and change the appName that way. It won't change the directory name for you, but you can do that yourself.

Comment: i didn't found **project/Build.scala** in my application, iam using play framework 1.2.5

Comment: @Yusuf1494 sbt was added in Play 2. I'm not sure how to do the same thing in 1.x

Comment: For Play 2.5.x, this setting is in "build.sbt" in the project's root folder.

Answer (score 5):

For Play Framework 2.2.x you'll be able to specify the project name in the `build.sbt` file located in the project's root folder.